# Filling combo box of form with map layers name?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, databinding

While writing the code for adding all the layers in arcmap into combobox of a form, I am getting the error:

> 'Bestaurents.frmRestaurentviewer' does not contain a definition for cmblayer and no extention method 'cmblayer' accepting a first argument of type Bestaurents.frmRestaurentviewe could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly)

at last line:

```
frmRestaurentViewer prestViewer = new frmRestaurentViewer();
prestViewer.Show();

IMxDocument doc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap pMap = doc.FocusMap;

ILayer play = pMap.get_Layer(0);
prestViewer.cmblayer.Items.Add(play.Name);
```

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more code than this, such as frmRestaurentViewer().  cmblayer is apparently not being set in the construction of the object.

Answer (score 1):

When your form is opened and then closed then your combo box `cmblayer` is disposed. so it is null.

To solve this situation, handle your from load event (create a method and event listener) and put your codes there:

```
private void frmRestaurentViewer_OnFormLoadEvent()
{
IMxDocument doc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap pMap = doc.FocusMap;

ILayer play = pMap.get_Layer(0);
prestViewer.cmblayer.Items.Add(play.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code block will only pull items that are currently in your table of contents:

```
/// <summary> Returns a list of feature layers based on the geometry type </summary>
    /// <param name="geometryType">Geometry type.  Expected values "Point", "Line" or "Polygon".</param>
    /// <returns>Arraylist</returns>
    public ArrayList FeatureLayers(string geometryType)
    {
        ArrayList pList = new ArrayList();
        if (FocusMap == null)
            return pList;
        if (FocusMap.LayerCount == 0)
            return pList;

        try
        {
            UID pID = new UIDClass();
            pID.Value = "{E156D7E5-22AF-11D3-9F99-00C04F6BC78E}"; //GeoFeatureLayer
            IEnumLayer pEnumLayer = FocusMap.get_Layers(pID, true);
            pEnumLayer.Reset();
            ILayer pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next();
            while (!(pLayer == null))
            {
                if (pLayer is IFeatureLayer)
                {
                    IFeatureLayer featurelayer = (IFeatureLayer)pLayer;
                    if (string.Compare(geometryType, "Point", true) == 0)
                    {
                        if ((featurelayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryMultipoint) || (featurelayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint))
                            pList.Add(pLayer.Name);
                    }
                    if (string.Compare(geometryType, "Line", true) == 0)
                    {
                        if ((featurelayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline) || (featurelayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryLine))
                            pList.Add(pLayer.Name);
                    }
                    if (string.Compare(geometryType, "Polygon", true) == 0)
                    {
                        if (featurelayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType == esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon)
                            pList.Add(pLayer.Name);
                    }
                }
                pLayer = pEnumLayer.Next();
            }
            return pList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (SupressMessaging == false)
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "All Layers", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        return pList;
    }
```

Here is an example of the method being implemented

```
private void LoadComboBox()
    {
        _application = this.Hook as IApplication;
        _mxdocument = (IMxDocument)_application.Document;
        _map = _mxdocument.FocusMap;
        _activeView = _mxdocument.ActivatedView;

        comboBox.Items.Clear();

        this.comboBox.Items.AddRange(FeatureLayers("Polygon").ToArray());
        if (this.comboBox.Items.Count > -1) this.comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```